# HTTP Post Request With list as data param

Tags: java, json, http, automated-tests, web-api-testing

I am trying to write an automation test case to validate a service, which accept list as http body/data parameter. When I am performing this operation via browser, its working as expected (below is curl of successful request)

```
curl 'https://mytest.org.com/admin/addValue' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'CSRF_TOKEN: 18243bk3lu8hakfosidu56b40de4356dkm3u643j0e2ldcsc85si' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: dslang=US-EN; ac9-at=Nq41QacCjw2tdOUBw6aKlq/yybAARv9GvFe/F; geo=US; cpl=Dsuy09ercyiX9MfjSvjDKPq45Qgqe+0gp81c4DFb000=' --data '[{"label":"MultiValueId","value":"California","instanceId":2049}]'
```

Although, when same I am trying with my automation suite, values are not getting saved as expected -

```
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://mytest.org.com/admin/addValue");
        httppost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, "keep-alive");
        httppost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.2 Safari/604.4.7");
        httppost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
        httppost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate,br");
        httppost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, "en-us");
        httppost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        httppost.addHeader("CSRF_TOKEN", MyConstant.CSRF_TOKEN);
        httppost.addHeader("Cookie", MyConstant.cookie);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> valParameters=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        valParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("label", "MultiValueId"));
        valParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", "California"));
        valParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("instanceId", "2049"));

        List postParameters=new ArrayList<Object>();
        postParameters.add(valParameters);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters, "UTF-8"));
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        System.out.println(httppost.toString());
        HttpResponse resp = HttpsSSLClient.createSSLInsecureClient().execute(httppost);
        System.out.println("Response --> " + resp.toString()+resp.getEntity());
        System.out.println("Response Entity--> " + resp.getEntity());
```

Below is the http post data param -

> [{"label":"MultiValueId","value":"DEF","instanceId":2049},{"label":"MultiValueId","value":"GHI","instanceId":2049}]

Also, i came to know that below is how service is written at application end i.e. it accept list as a parameter -

```
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Path("/addValue")

  public ValueUploadResponse addLabelValue(List<GenericUXData> fieldList)  {

        ValueUploadResponse response = new ValueUploadResponse();
        List<GenericUXData> savedValues = new ArrayList<GenericUXData>();
        List<GenericUXData> errorValues = new ArrayList<GenericUXData>();
        if (fieldList == null || fieldList.size() < 1) {
              response.setErrorMessage("No Field List Found");
              return response;
        }
......
......
......
```

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: please post GenericUXData.java

Comment: https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-send-post-request-with-a-json-body-using-the-httpclient/  this will solve your problem, you need to pass your parameter in body

Comment: Thanks @GaneshGudghe ! I tried the approach mentioned above but still noticing that values are not getting saved. Used below as data:                                                                                      String payload = "data=[{" +
                    "\"label\": \"MultiValueId\", " +
                    "\"value\": \"LAN\", " +
                    "\"instanceId\": 2049" +
                    "}]";

Comment: Also, GenericUXData.java is just a java bean class with above three set of properties.

Comment: try without data  like  [{" + "\"label\": \"MultiValueId\", " + "\"value\": \"LAN\", " + "\"instanceId\": 2049" + "}]